# find union of a particular row values with two row values in different dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, union

I have two data frame dfa and dfb

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfa = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,0,0,1,0], [1,1,1,0,0]]))
dfa

dfb = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1]]))
dfb
```

Now, I need overwrite data frame dfa first row by taking union of data frame dfb first row and second row

```
[1,0,0,1,0] union [1,1,0,1,0]  union [0,0,1,0,0] = [1,1,1,1,0]
```

final data dfa frame I need look like below

dfa

```
    0  1  2  3  4
0   1  1  1  1  0
1   1  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How can I overwrite data frame dfa first row by taking union with data frame dfb first row and second row

Comment: `dfa.iloc[0] = np.maximum(dfb.iloc[:2].max().values, dfa.iloc[0])`.